# Not able to hit the image element which works as a button in ui?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am a newbee to selenium webdriver by using python
Below is the configuration:

```
 Selenium WebDriver: selenium-2.40.0(Python bindings)
 Python Version    : Python 2.7
 OS                : Windows
```

I have tried hitting the mentioned control through the xpath and the css selector in my script but was unable to hit that control.I also crosschecked it in the xpath viewer with the xpath, it was showing it there .I also tried to hit the control with the css selector but it was not hitting it.I am able to access other controls that are there on the webpage using `css` selector and `xpath`.I have also attached the `HTML` code with the xpath and css selector syntax i am using in my code.

The Xpath I am using for the script is : `find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='Expand All' and @alt='Expand All']")`

The css selector i am using in my script is : `find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='lnk1'][onClick*='treeTable(expandAll)']")`

```
<table width="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <td width="">
 <a class="lnk1" onfocus="" onclick="this.style.cursor='wait';document.body.style.cursor='wait'; return doTblAjax('WTableForm_453ea28b', 'action_453ea28b', 'treeTable(expandAll)', 'tableTop_453ea28b', 'action_453ea28b', 'wh', 'wa', event);" onblur="" href="/hmc/bonsai/action/T56?wh=action_453ea28b&action_453ea28b=treeTable%28expandAll%29&timestamp=144e404faf0#tableTop_453ea28b">
 <img class="tbl9" width="32" border="0" align="top" height="32" title="Expand All" src="/wclres/wcl/images/tretbl1.gif" role="button" onmouseover="className='tbl10'" onmouseout="className='tbl9'" alt="Expand All">
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS Selector

The Safe Method css=div.someClass'] a[contains(@onclick,'treeTable(expandAll)')] > img

This will be serving as unique xpath for Expand Button.

Thanks!

Comment: It got solved.. Actually I was missing one frame to switch... Any ways thanks for the reply..